# Open VPN UDP link local: (not bound) error

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, vpn

I've been following [this](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-vpn-server/) guide and the setup of PiVPN has gone smoothly until connecting the client to the server. I get this error:

```
TLS Error: TLS handshake failed along wth the error in the title
```

I have port forwarded my Pi 3 to 1194 (UDP) only and I'm running Duck DNS on the Pi. I'm new to this stuff so help is appreciated.